# how do I access object tags in aspx.cs page?

Tags: asp.net, html, object

I desingned a page with  tags, Now I want to access object tags in code behind.

This is aspx page code....

```
<object type="label" runat="server" class="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label" id="label_priority" parent="-1" bindedfield="priority" empty="1" value="MyValue">
```

Here I am adding `runat=server` in object tags it is giving error as

```
"An object tag must contain a Class, ClassID or ProgID attribute."
```

then I added `class="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label"`, now not giving any error but not showing anything in browser.

so My question is how do I access object tags in aspx.cs page?
or 
I want to create a label with object tag that is accessible in code behind.

Sujeet

Comment: +1 never heard of this 'object-tag' and apparently it does exist: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8k45y06.aspx

Answer (score 4):

When you have runat="server" on a <object/> or <script/> tag, .NET expects it to be a server side object. You can however create the entire markup on the server side. Assuming you have `<div id="somecontainer" runat="server"></div>` in your page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    HtmlGenericControl myObject = new HtmlGenericControl();
    myObject.TagName = "object";
    myObject.Attributes.Add("data", "somevideo.mpeg");
    Page.FindControl("somecontainer").Controls.Add(myObject);
}
```

The result is:

```
<div id="somecontainer"><object data="somevideo.mpeg"></object></div>
```

You can use the same method to add elements inside the object, for instance <param/> tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below like code in your page load event if you want to access this in page load :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page,Page.GetType(), "Script", "document.getElementById('DIVID').style.display='none'",true);
```

Here we are changing the display property of the div .you can change according to your requirement.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
<object id="items" class = "System.Collections.ArrayList"  runat="server">
```

as it is run at server now , you can accessing from code behind